df from structured list; list of dicts with nested list of dicts as values
Trying to convert this to a DataFrame.
list structure:
[
    {'Name': '#NAME',
     'Business Unit': '#UNIT',
     'Managed': 'Yes',
     'Date': '01/30/2023 3:37 AM',
     'Permissions': 
        [
            {'Group Name': '#NAME1','Table Name': '#TABLE1',...},
            {'Group Name': '#NAME1','Table Name': '#TABLE2',...},
            {'Group Name': '#NAME2','Table Name': '#TABLE3',...},
            {'Group Name': '#NAME2','Table Name': '#TABLE4',...},
            ...
        ]
    },
    {'Name': '#NAME',
     'Business Unit': '#UNIT',
     'Managed': 'Yes',
     'Date': '01/30/2023 3:37 AM',
     'Permissions': 
        [
            {'Group Name': '#NAME1','Table Name': '#TABLE1',...},
            {'Group Name': '#NAME1','Table Name': '#TABLE2',...},
            {'Group Name': '#NAME2','Table Name': '#TABLE3',...},
            {'Group Name': '#NAME2','Table Name': '#TABLE4',...},
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
]
     

where

every key in the bottom-level dict is a column
each 'Table Name' is a new row

in the resulting DataFrame.  I tried using from_dict, json_normalize, from_records, but they make a single Permissions column as a list of dicts.

Assuming lst the input and using json_normalize:
df = pd.json_normalize(lst, 'Permissions',
                       meta=['Name', 'Business Unit', 'Managed', 'Date'])

Output:
  Group Name Table Name   Name Business Unit Managed                Date
0     #NAME1    #TABLE1  #NAME         #UNIT     Yes  01/30/2023 3:37 AM
1     #NAME1    #TABLE2  #NAME         #UNIT     Yes  01/30/2023 3:37 AM
2     #NAME2    #TABLE3  #NAME         #UNIT     Yes  01/30/2023 3:37 AM
3     #NAME2    #TABLE4  #NAME         #UNIT     Yes  01/30/2023 3:37 AM
4     #NAME1    #TABLE1  #NAME         #UNIT     Yes  01/30/2023 3:37 AM
5     #NAME1    #TABLE2  #NAME         #UNIT     Yes  01/30/2023 3:37 AM
6     #NAME2    #TABLE3  #NAME         #UNIT     Yes  01/30/2023 3:37 AM
7     #NAME2    #TABLE4  #NAME         #UNIT     Yes  01/30/2023 3:37 AM

